# Group Windows by Application in Windows Alt-Tab

Tags: windows, keyboard-shortcuts, tabs

Being developer, I have 20+ tabs are in Alt-Tab view [mostly from 4-5 applications]. In OSX, you can switch between different windows of sample application using shortcut. Is there any such shortcut available in Windows.

Another biggest problem is if I `alt-tab`, all of these 20 tabs are present without any grouping. Is there a way to group them by application and navigate?

Comment: What version of Windows are you on?

Comment: Windows 10 latest version

Comment: There is the ability to make multiple "desktops" in windows 10. I'm not sure how it behaves with the `alt-tab` menu because i have some mods that may be interfering, but it might be something to look into.

Comment: Got the same problem. Ubuntu got `alt-`` for that function, and I am also looking for an alternative on my office machine which runs windows 10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found free tool for the same. https://neosmart.net/EasySwitch/.
This is quite lightweight and I am living with this product for more than 3 months.

Comment: Does this work on Windows 10? I've installed Easy Switch but alt + tab is behaving the same default way. Are there any extra settings to be made? If yes, then how? As the app doesn't provide any means to do it. Just an installer.

Comment: The description of this tool says it only adds same-app window switching to alt-backtick. It does not say anything about grouping apps with alt-tab.

Comment: Can you confirm Reddy?

Answer (score 0):

**United Sets**

An open-sourced program that groups windows into tabs, inspired by the unreleased Sets feature

[image]

https://github.com/FireCubeStudios/UnitedSets
https://apps.microsoft.com/store/detail/united-sets-beta-indev
(At time time in BETA)

- Windows 10 x64

Answer (score -2):

in settings ... check multitasking tab ... there u ll find, alt + tab feature enable and disable group options ...

for more chek dis link - https://www.howtogeek.com/352028/windows-10-is-changing-how-alttab-works-here%E2%80%99s-what-you-need-to-know/

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link(s), as the answer can become invalid if the linked page(s) change.

Comment: Not sure why this answer is voted down, but in windows 11 this solves the problem. And his answer is short and concise. the only difference is that now it's not an enable/disable, but a dropdown list of options where you can choose how much tab you want to be displayed in your choices.